# jsf Invoking Arbitrary Methods via EL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

I am starter on JSF and have trouble with invokation of arbitrary methods via EL.
According to what I read version 2.1 of the Unified Expression Language, included in Java EE 6, has support for invoking arbitrary methods and passing arguments to them.
I am using MyFaces2.0.3, JRE6Up21, Tomcat 6.0.29 and Eclipse.
I have the following snippet in a facelet:

```
<h:form>
<p>
<h:link outcome="NextPage" value="Link for Next Page">
<f:param name="word1" value="hello" />
<f:param name="word2" value="world" />
</h:link>
</p>
</h:form>
```

and in the facelet NextPage.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<p>
This is the method invocation #{model.printArgs(param.word1,param.word2)}
</p>
</h:form>
```

`Model` is a managed bean(request scoped) that has this method `printArgs` that returns a string concatenation of word1 and word2.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Model {

public String printArgs(String word1, String word2) {
        String result = "No arguments??????";

        if (null != word1 && !word1.isEmpty() && null != word2 && !word2.isEmpty()) {
            result = word1+" "+word2;
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

When I press the link the url is http://localhost:8080/RegJSF/faces/NextPage.xhtml?word1=hello&word2=world
but I get the error

> org.apache.el.parser.ParseException:
>   Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1,
>   column 25. Was expecting one of: "}"
>   ... "." ... "[" ... ">" ... "gt" ...
>   "<" ... "lt" ... ">=" ... "ge" ...
>   "<=" ... etc

If i remove `#{model.printArgs(param.word1,param.word2)}` the NextPage is loaded, so the problem is the method invocation.
What is the problem here? Is it configuration issue?
**Note** Same issue if I use Mojarra2.0.3
Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, are you trying to invoke method on page load, is it ?

Comment: @org.life.java:I click on the link, the url is as I mention and I pass the parameters via the URL and in NextPage.xhtml, the method should be called passing in the parameters and the page would render: `"This is the method invocation hello world!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to what I read version 2.1 of the Unified Expression Language, included in Java EE 6, has support for invoking arbitrary methods and passing arguments to them.

I think you are mistaken. This support was introduced in JSP 2.2 (which is required to meet the JEE6 spec).

From the [JSP 2.2 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html):

> **Changes between Maintenance 1 and Maintenance Release 2**
>
> The main change in this release is the
>   addition of method invokations with
>   parameters in the EL, such as
>   `#{trader.buy(“JAVA”)}`.

Since Tomcat 6 is a JSP 2.1 container, you might consider upgrading to Tomcat 7.

Comment: Tested with Tomcat 7 and it works.It seems you are right.So for invocation with params I should use Tomcat 7 although it is in beta?

Comment: @user384706 - implementations for the most recent Servlet and JSP specs are still a bit thin on the ground. I'm not aware of any that are GA other than Glassfish 3 and JBoss 6 (full JEE servers). I believe you can get equivalent functionality with JBoss EL/Seam 2.2, but I'm not sure what the compatibility story is with this stack.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
This is the method invocation <h:outputText value="#{model.printArgs(param.word1,param.word2)}"/>
```

Double quotes are necessary here. Also, try outputText instead.

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov:Same problem with the double quotes as well. Dummy question:Is EL2.1 enabled by default?

Comment: updated the answer. Try this h:outputText tag. What JSF version do you use?

Comment: @Vladimir:I copy-pasted it.Eclipse warns as syntax error in EL underlying in orange the `(param.word1,param.word2)`, I run the app anyway but still same error `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /NextPage.xhtml at line 12 and column 153 value="#model.printArgs(param.word1,param.word2)}" Error Parsing: #{model.printArgs(param.word1,param.word2)}`. I am using MyFaces2.0.3

Comment: I'm asking not about MyFaces version, but the version of JSF. Is it 2.0?

Comment: @Vladimir:How do I check that version?

Comment: @Vladimir:I am including MyFacesImpl2.0.3. Doesn't this mean JSF 2.0?