# Jsf use property instead of methods on xhml pages

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I faced with very strange thing in my work.

I read that calling service methods in getter is a bad practise. Because when the page is rendered getter and setters can be called many times and every time select data from db for example for one admin who can change data it's not logical as I think.

That's why I try to separate getters and methods. But sometimes I want to call maethods not property on the page. But when my colleague tells me that when he uses this methods with brackets he gets error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /admin/tournament/manageTournament.xhtml @147,127 rendered="#{not empty adminTournamentController.selectTeamsByConditions()}": The class 'by.bvf.web.controller.tournament.AdminTournamentController' does not have the property 'selectTeamsByConditions'.
```

I think we use the same version of library. What can be the reason of problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you use libraries with same Expression Language version? Because in older EL there isn't possible to use methods like you did. Try to change it to `#{not empty (adminTournamentController.selectTeamsByConditions())}` - maybe it will work. Otherwise your EL doesn't understand expresion with `()` and try to read `selectTeamsByConditions` just as field.

Comment: Check here for better understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552580/jsf-invoking-arbitrary-methods-via-el

Comment: Show us some of your bean

Comment: what server are you using? if you are using tomcat 6 you should remove parenthesis. besides that, maybe when you use "not empty" jsf expects a property afterwards. a workaround would be to change the method name in the bean to getSelectTeamsByConditions(). that way it will see it like a property

Comment: You are mixing properties and methods. In that `rendered` attribute JSF expects a property, so it's going to use `getSelectTeamsByConditions()` getter to access it. But what you expect is an action method which is called `selectTeamsByConditions()`. Take care about that. In order to access data via the getter methods the best practices recommend loading it in bean creation (`@postConstruct` method) or action methods and assign no logic to the getters.